# Why is there a difference between servertimestamp and the js new Date() in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

While writing a doc to the Firestore, I often see that the difference between the `serverTimestamp()` sentinel and the `new Date()` object is non-zero.

The difference ranges between a *few* seconds to *tens* of minutes.

Aren't they doing the same thing?

[image]

Code for the example in Cloud Functions

```
docRef.set({
  'date-timestamp': new Date(),
  'server-timestamp': admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
}).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not doing the same thing.

`serverTimestamp()` converts to the date as reckoned by Google servers, at the time the document write was received at the server.

`new Date()` yields the date as reckoned by the client at the time the Date object was created, regardless of any other factors.

Obviously, in your example, the reckoning of time is different between the client and the server.  There will always be some difference, as there is latency between the client and the server that can't be avoided.

Comment: Although this is an old thread, I'd like to add one thing. Using the serverTimestamp placeholder will be executed afterwards on the server, meaning that it will trigger an update on the document so basically you are creating the doc and then it has to update for the placeholder to actually update the date. This will trigger a firestore function trigger onUpdate so this is something to keep in mind